# Powershell script not unzipping remote folder to location

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy

I have a powershell step in Octopus deploy to copy some pre-requisite files from a zip file on a remote machine before I deploy a website.

```
$source='\\RemoteMachine\Artifacts\ZipFile.zip\ChildFolder\FolderToCopy'
$target='C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Web'; 

if (!(Test-Path $target -PathType Container))
{
  New-Item $target -Type Directory;
  Write-Output "Created folder $target";
}

$shellApplication = New-Object -com shell.application;
$zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($source);
$targetFolder = $shellApplication.NameSpace($target);

Write-Output "Copying files...";
$targetFolder.CopyHere($zipPackage.Items()) 
Write-Output "Copy done";
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working, I get an error of

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Tentacle\Temp\c2f0444d-f099-49ce-ad17-a8aa47c4703b.ps1:15 char:1

+ $targetFolder.CopyHere($zipPackage.Items())

+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

The error seems to point to the `CopyHere` line, when I change `$zipPackage.Items()` to just `$zipPackage` the powershell script runs but nothing gets deployed.

When I run this locally on the machine, it seems to work fine, but when I run the same thing via octopus deploy, it doesn't work

Comment: This is not a full error, what's above `+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~` line?

Comment: I've just updated the error

Comment: Looks like octopus is passing wrong path somewhere as `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Tentacle\Temp\c2f0444` does not appear anywhere in your code, right? I take the script works if you just run it in your own shell window?

Comment: Yep seems to work fine when I run it manually, but I think that 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Tentacle\Temp\c2f0444' is where it copys the script before running it

Comment: I've updated the error, I noticed that it didn't past correctly

Comment: This is the crux of the issue here, `$source` does not exist and is why `$zipPackage` equals null. If you pass the correct path in the script should behave as expected.

Comment: $source does exist, if I run the script manually in  (no changes) on the target machine it runs fine.

Comment: Add these 2 lines above `Write-Output "Copying files...";`, they will help you troubleshoot which object is causing problem `echo ("zipPackage is null:" + ($zipPackage -eq $null)) >> $logfile`
`echo ("targetFolder is null:" + ($targetFolder -eq $null)) >> $logfile`.
Make sure to set `$logfile`.